# Question about criterion of measurability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, and in Theorem 1.12, Rudin states that

Let $M$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ and $Y$ be a topological space.

Let $f$ be a function from $X$ into $Y$

Then, if $Y = [-\infty,\infty]$ and $f^{-1}({(\alpha,\infty]})\in M$ for every real $\alpha$, then $f$ is measurable.

Then Rudin writes
"This is a frequently used criterion for the measurability of real-valued function"

But isn't the function $f$ extended real-valued?

Why does Rudin say just real-valued?

Comment: Laziness? Slip of attention? I don't think there was a deep reason not to write "real-valued or extended-real-valued", it just happened.

Comment: I was just wondering about that, because he proves it for extened-real-valued case, but then says that it is a criterion for real-valed fnction

Comment: Also, if $f$ is real-valued function, then don't we need to use $(\alpha,+\infty)$ i.e. not including positive infity?

Comment: Real-valued functions are also extended-real-valued functions. If $f$ is real-valued, then $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty)) = f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty])$. While formally, if you consider the codomain $\mathbb{R}$, the expression $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty])$ can be considered malformed, making such distinctions pointlessly complicates matters. It is clear what $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty])$ means anyway.